# How to click on a button with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I try to catch the "next" button in a viewer with Selenium in Python, but nothing works and I get an error message.

The code I executed:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://web.nli.org.il/sites/NLI/Hebrew/digitallibrary/pages/viewer.aspx?&presentorid=MANUSCRIPTS&docid=PNX_MANUSCRIPTS990000907570205171-1')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
```

Until now, everything has been fine. This is where the issue arises.

I want to click on the next arrow:
[image]

I get the following code while inspecting the source code of this arrow:
`<div id="next" class="left"><a href="#" title="next">&nbsp;</a></div>`

So these are my attempts:

**XPath**

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="next"]')
```

returns an empty list.

**id**

```
driver.find_elements_by_id("next")
```

returns an empty list.

So, *how can I catch this button and click on it?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That arrow is in iframe, so driver needs to change it's focus.

and then you can use `explicit wait` to click on it :

**CSS_SELECTOR :**

```
div#next
```

**Sample code  :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('URL here')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "MainIframe")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#next"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use below css selectors:

1. `.left [title='Next']`
2. `div.left`
3. `div .left [title='Next']`

Answer (score 1):

`//div[@id='next']//child::a` there could be different element with the id `next` so specifically define for the `div` and, I can see the `a` is the child of `div`

you can check it with the explicitWait

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='next']//child::a"))).click()
```

Also found an `iframe` with the `id = MainIframe` and `name = zoomer`
under which the desired element is available, so you could switch
to the frame and get the desired element